# Enable/disable a button on entering the values in multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have five text boxes and a submit button.

By default, my submit button is disabled.

I want that, on filling the values in all the text boxes, button should be enabled.

button should not enable after filling only some text boxes.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your code

Comment: Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### jQuery Solution

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Rqm/1/)**

```
function doCheck(){
    var allFilled = true;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            allFilled = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(doCheck).focusout(doCheck);
});
```

### Plain Javascript Solution

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zCqjN/1/)**

This requires the submit button have an ID of `mysubmit`:

```
function doCheck(){
    var allFilled = true;

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == "text" && inputs[i].value == ''){
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("mysubmit").disabled = !allFilled;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == "text"){
            inputs[i].onkeyup = doCheck;
            inputs[i].onblur = doCheck;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
var inputs = $('input');
inputs.keypress(function() {
   var count = 0;
   inputs.each(function() {
       if ($(this).val()) {
           count++
       }
   });
   if (count === inputs.length-1) {
      // enable the button
   } else {
      // disable the button so it will be disabled if someone remove the text
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code happens to be like below

```
<form name="urfrm">
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox1" class="txtboxtocheck"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox2" class="txtboxtocheck"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox3" class="txtboxtocheck"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox4" class="txtboxtocheck"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox5" class="txtboxtocheck"><br>
<input type="submit" id="butn" name="butn" value="POST VAL" disabled><br>
</form>
<script>
```

By using jquery you can determine whether text boxes are empty or filled using below code and enable / disable the submit button

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(".txtboxtocheck").change(function(){
    var enablebtn = true;
    $(".txtboxtocheck").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '')
            enablebtn = false;
    });

    if(enablebtn)
        $("#butn").attr('disabled',false);
    else
        $("#butn").attr('disabled',true);
});

</script>
```

Below is plain javascript that check if text boxes are empty to enables / disables

```
<form name="urfrm">
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox1" class="txtboxtocheck" onchange="checktxtbox()"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox2" class="txtboxtocheck" onchange="checktxtbox()"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox3" class="txtboxtocheck" onchange="checktxtbox()"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox4" class="txtboxtocheck" onchange="checktxtbox()"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="tbox5" class="txtboxtocheck" onchange="checktxtbox()"><br>
<input type="submit" id="butn" name="butn" value="POST VAL" disabled><br>
</form>
```

Javascript to check

```
<script>

function checktxtbox(){
    if(document.urfrm.tbox1.value != '' && document.urfrm.tbox2.value != '' && document.urfrm.tbox3.value != '' && document.urfrm.tbox4.value != '' && document.urfrm.tbox5.value != ''){
        document.urfrm.butn.disabled=false;
    }
    else{
        document.urfrm.butn.disabled=true;
    }
}
</script>
```